# SpriteKit animateWithTextures in iOS7 not working

Tags: ios, animation, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm trying to add a little animation based on two pngs, where I create two SKTextures with two images and create an SKAction, and have it run forever with [SKAction repeatActionForever] but nothing is happening, nothing is appearing on the screen.

Here's my code:

```
_planePropeller = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"PLANE PROPELLER 1.png"];
        _planePropeller.xScale = 0.2;
        _planePropeller.yScale = 0.2;
        _planePropeller.position = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2, _plane.size.height+10);
        SKTexture *propeller1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"PLANE PROPELLER 1.png"];
        SKTexture *propeller2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"PLANE PROPELLER 2.png"];
        SKAction *spin = [SKAction animateWithTextures:@[propeller1, propeller2] timePerFrame:0.1];
        SKAction *spinForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:spin];
        [_planePropeller runAction:spinForever];
        [self addChild:_planePropeller];
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please see this i think it will help you http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: keep in mind that filenames are case sensitive on a device, so if your filenames really are "Plane Propeller 1.png" it won't load the files.

Comment: yes, I checked it, but they're correct as I wrote them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So my problem was, actually, my own ignorance, since I first was adding my `SKNodes`, and the last, when the background should have been added the first, so it could be on the background :)

thanks a lot everybody for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

could be your positioning details, are you sure they are correct? I've changed your code slightly (self.frame.size.width instead of screenWidth and the same for height, to position it in the centre of the view) and it works for me:

```
- (SKNode *)propellorNode
{
SKNode *planePropeller = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"image1.png"];
planePropeller.xScale = 0.2;
planePropeller.yScale = 0.2;
planePropeller.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
SKTexture *propeller1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"image1.png"];
SKTexture *propeller2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"image2.png"];
SKAction *spin = [SKAction animateWithTextures:@[propeller1, propeller2]    timePerFrame:0.1];
SKAction *spinForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:spin];
[planePropeller runAction:spinForever];
return planePropeller;
}
```